# Bootstrap Inherit Grid/CSS Width Options From Grandparent

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Having a template like following in Bootstrap 3:

```
<style>
.chart{width: 9999px;}
</style>

<div class="container">
  <div class="well"> 
   <div class="row">
    <div class="chart">
      <div class="thumbnail col-md-3 col-md-3"></div>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

is it possible to inherit size (width) of the `.thumbnail` from `.row` class and skip the `.chart` while the `.chart` has a with property with 9999px as below image:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say if you need a more specific solution since I don't have the exact context of the situation, but you could do this:

```
.row .thumbnail {width: 500px;}
```

That will override the `.chart` CSS for all `thumbnail` classes that are children of `row` classes.

**[Bootply Demo](http://www.bootply.com/ZuTEinBxuz)**

Separately, you don't need to have two `col-md-3` classes in the same element, the second `col-md-3` doesn't change anything.